# Making a link from an animation (on hover) run by javascript in a tabular layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

I have the following code, a simple three column layout with an animation running on hover in each.

The animation works fine, but I cannot make the animation button a link. It has the image as the link, and if I change the href, it fails (which makes sense) but I cannot figure out where to add the link in.

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <a href="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children-anim.gif" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children.gif" 
                    data-orig="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children.gif" width="323" height="323"></a>                      
                    </td>


                    <td>
                    <a href="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-teenagers-anim.gif" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-teenagers.gif" 
                    data-orig="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-teenagers.gif" width="323" height="323"></a>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                    <a href="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-parents-anim.gif" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-parents.gif" 
                    data-orig="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-parents.gif" width="323" height="323"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Run by the following javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('table a img').hover(function(){
    // on mouse enter
    var customdata = $(this).parent().attr('href');
    $(this).attr('src',customdata); 
  }, function(){
    // on mouse leave
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-orig'));
  });

});
</script>
```

Is on page here [Link to homepage of site.](http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/en/Webteam-Development-Area/Paediatric-Homepage/)

Comment: The site looks like it's behaving appropriately.. when you click on the link, it links to the picture's image, e.g. `http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children-anim.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.. I'm not sure what link you actually want or why your current implementation is wrong.  I'm going to assume that you don't want a link to an image as the actual link.  If that assumption is right, here's your answer...

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <a href="[Your Link Goes Here]" target="_blank">
           <img 
src="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children.gif"  
data-img="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children.gif"
data-animation="http://www.gloshospitals.nhs.uk/templates/standard/images/paeds/for-children-anim.gif" 
width="323" height="323"></a>                      
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('table a img').hover(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var animateUrl = element.data('animation');
    element.attr('src', animateUrl);  
  }, function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var staticImage = element.data('img');
    element.attr('src', staticImage); 
  });

});
</script>
```